# Is there a way to retrieve Github repositories whose language has been changed?

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to get all repositories whose language was Java but had changed to Kotlin and vice versa.

Does anyone know if it's possible to filter these repositories with the Github api?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to compare before/after, in terms of a programming languages for particular GitHub repos, I'm not sure you can do that short of having a big-data project.

If you want to filter GitHub repos by programming language, the [GitHub API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories) states:

---

Suppose you want to search for popular Tetris repositories written in Assembly. Your query might look like this.

`curl https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=tetris+language:assembly&sort=stars&order=desc`

---

Also,
Checkout my open-soure project [Git-Captain](https://github.com/ConfusedDeer/Git-Captain), which may help you.

It's an open-source web-application built with Node.js utilizing GitHub API to find, create, and delete a branch throughout numerous GitHub repositories. 
Can be setup for organizations or a single user.

I have a step-by-step how to set it up on a server to communicate with the GitHub API.